# Get last unique JSON inputs in bash

Tags: json, select, timestamp, max, jq

I'm looking to pull the latest (by timestamp) source and message from some JSON data. I tried to get jq to pull only the latest unique message based on the source but can't quite figure it out.

Example source data is:

```
{"envelope":{"source":"+13101234567","sourceDevice":1,"relay":null,"timestamp":1610256979995,"dataMessage":{"timestamp":1610256979995,"message":"Yes","expiresInSeconds":0,"reaction":null,"quote":null,"mentions":[],"attachments":[],"groupInfo":null},"syncMessage":null,"callMessage":null,"receiptMessage":null}}
{"envelope":{"source":"+13102345678","sourceDevice":1,"relay":null,"timestamp":1610256985623,"dataMessage":{"timestamp":1610256985623,"message":"1","expiresInSeconds":0,"reaction":null,"quote":null,"mentions":[],"attachments":[],"groupInfo":null},"syncMessage":null,"callMessage":null,"receiptMessage":null}}
{"envelope":{"source":"+13102345678","sourceDevice":1,"relay":null,"timestamp":1610256987736,"dataMessage":{"timestamp":1610256987736,"message":"3","expiresInSeconds":0,"reaction":null,"quote":null,"mentions":[],"attachments":[],"groupInfo":null},"syncMessage":null,"callMessage":null,"receiptMessage":null}}
{"envelope":{"source":"+13101234567","sourceDevice":1,"relay":null,"timestamp":1610256990731,"dataMessage":{"timestamp":1610256990731,"message":"4","expiresInSeconds":0,"reaction":null,"quote":null,"mentions":[],"attachments":[],"groupInfo":null},"syncMessage":null,"callMessage":null,"receiptMessage":null}}
{"envelope":{"source":"+13105678901","sourceDevice":1,"relay":null,"timestamp":1610256990731,"dataMessage":{"timestamp":1610256990731,"message":"4","expiresInSeconds":0,"reaction":null,"quote":null,"mentions":[],"attachments":[],"groupInfo":null},"syncMessage":null,"callMessage":null,"receiptMessage":null}}
```

For this example, the result should be:

```
[{"source":"+13102345678","message":"3"},{"source":"+13101234567","message":"4"},{"source":"+13105678901","message":"4"}]
```

Using `.envelope.source,.envelope.dataMessage.message` gets the information without the headers but piping it into `unique[]` says "Cannot iterate over string" on [jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/bn5WYbOcZx).

Comment: By "latest" do you mean with respect to the .timestamp values?

Comment: By timestamp would be fine. I've added that to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the question, a reasonable solution would be as follows, assuming the -n command-line option is used:

```
[inputs.envelope
 | {source, 
    message: .dataMessage.message,
    timestamp: .dataMessage.timestamp}]
| group_by(.source)
| [ .[] | max_by(.timestamp) | {source, message} ]
```

This at least produces the expected results, and pays attention to the "timestamps".